# Obtener el nombre de un objeto en javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Quiero obtener el nombre de un objeto creado y no sé cómo hacerlo, es decir, si tengo el siguiente objeto:

```html
const cocheBMW = {
    marca: 'BMW',
    modelo: 'i30',
    acelerar: function () { return 'El coche ha acelerado' }
}
```

Quiero obtener "cocheBMW" como string para utilizarlo, no como objeto, sino únicamente el nombre que tiene el objeto.

Lo que quiero conseguir es que introduciendo un objeto en una función me aparezca un mensaje así:

```html
function mostrarCoche(objeto) {
console.log(
    `El objeto ${objeto} proviene de la clase: ${objeto.constructor.name}`);
}
```

El motivo es solo académico, si en algún momento quiero saber el nombre del objeto creado automáticamente o viene de un código que no he escrito yo.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres conseguir, realmente? Es decir, estás pidiendo que el código tenga información sobre si mismo, lo cual suele ser una muy mala idea, pero no nos cuentas qué quieres hacer con esa información y seguramente haya una forma mejor de hacerlo

Comment: Lo más sencillo: `const objectName = "cocheBMW";`

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo tu caso de uso, ya que el nombre de la variable lo estás declarando tu mismo al crearla, sin embargo, esto te podría ayudar:

```js
const cocheBMW = {
    marca: 'BMW',
    modelo: 'i30',
    acelerar: function () { return 'El coche ha acelerado' }
};

const objectName = Object.keys({ cocheBMW })[0];
console.log(objectName);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Utilizo el método [`keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), para obtener el nombre de la clave del objeto creado usando la variable `cocheBMW`. En fin, que esto es simplemente un forma rebuscada de obtener algo que ya tienes de antemano.